# MySQL DB with 3,000+ records that need to be converted

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database, that was an initial dump of an Excel file via phpmyadmin. So no formatting or other logic was applied to the table. So I am essentially left with a table of "varchar" style rows. Of which include things like dates and times.

Example:
start_time, end_time, start_date, end_date .. which look like 7:30 PM, 11:00PM, 9/9/12, 11/22/12 and then some rows that are fine just the way they are. Unfortunately I can't convert the whole table to a better format as someone based a lot of functionality around this lousy design of whats called a table. The only thing truely going for it, is the table has an auto incremented ID for each row that I can associate with something. So I figure as a means of Patching things up while we fix a lot of this functionality that strips things apart and all else I could make a bridge of sorts.

Make a table that can have proper types of rows for the data types, and then be able to use some mysql functionality like `BETWEEN()` for example on start_date to get a listing of a - z but a limited listing.

So I am trying to figure out is there a way I can dump data from one table to the next but in the process of this query have it convert it over to the types I want such as datetime, combining start_date and start_time into a datetime format and likewise with the end times/dates?

Or is this something I am going to have to pull out in a heap, loop over it with PHP and have it insert new rows into the new table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do that with a PHP script to read the original data and then process it into the correct date formats, then insert to the new table.

So the scenario is, you have a time and date separated and you want to combine them, then format them to the DB acceptable date format. I would do something like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

// you have separate dates and times like this
$date = '9/9/12';
$time = '11:00 PM';

// combine them into one string
$str = $date . ' ' . $time;

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('n/j/y g:i A', $str);

$DBFormat = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo $DBFormat;
// outputs DB date format -> 2012-09-09 23:00:00
```

One thing I noticed was your first time example was `7:30 PM` and the next example was `11:00PM`. In the latter example, there is no space before the `PM`. I don't know if that is a typo on your part or if your data does vary like that, if it does then I would add a check and insert the space.

Comment: Yea, thats what I was thinking, I was hoping I could get away with doing it straight through a query of some sort. But I already set up the new table, and all else, so guess no pain in writing a script to do it to it. Only problem I have currently is I have no idea what the origin of the timestamp for the times are that are listed, as in are they eastern, pacific, central, mountain, other.. ill have to find that out I suppose. Thanks

Comment: @chris I would opt for a PHP script to process the data rather than a large query/stored procedure because I think it will be easier to debug and add complex logic if needed.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can follow the steps:

1. Create a new table in the same DB which have all the fields in the source table(the table that going to copy).
2. Create a PHP file.
3. write a MYSQL query to select all the values in the source table.
4. In the while loop, write a query to insert these rows into the new table.
5. before that convert the value of start_time, end_time, start_date, end_date columns to the required format using "strtotime() and date()" functions in php.
6. insert the new values in the new table.